# Windows Server 2008 R2 FTP different permissions for internet and local network users

Tags: networking, permissions, ftp, windows-server-2008-r2

I got a task with strange requirements. I have to set up IIS FTP server with two folders for example F1 and F2. F1 should be available for read for all users (without authorization). F2 should be available for write only for users from local network.

Is it possible to set up that permissions on folder in IIS?

Comment: Being pragmatic, I think you need to put some thought into how you create those users, i.e. not just dump them all into one container. Your question doesn't seem to indicate that you have put much thought into this yet.